# seven kinds of trouble?

Tags: meaning

I dropped into a dark shadow, took a lungful of air and let it out in a howl—the snarling howl of a gray timber wolf, lonely and hungry and far from home, and mean enough for **seven kinds of trouble**.

For above sentence, the writer uses 'seven kinds of trouble' instead of many kinds of trouble. (I think it is the meaning.)

Is there any reason in English they seem to prefer the number '7' to other numbers? Like seven deadly sins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're  correct in the reference to the 7 deadly sins. Most authors, when using the number 7 in terms of trouble, evil, etc..; are referring to the seven deadly sins metaphor.

Comment: A conscious allusion to the Seven Deadly Sins might be true of some authors, but the number seven is a common number in folksy sayings. Compare "seven ways to Sunday".

Comment: I agree with TRomano - to me it just means "copious amounts of trouble."